# ArcGis null values in interpolation tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, interpolation, arcgis-9.2, null

I'm making some maps in ArcGIS for some geochemical data. I have some null values in my attribute table but when I use the interpolation tools (kriging or inverse distance)  the null values are automaticaly considered as zero.

Is there a way I could make the interpolation tool to ignore the points where there is a null value insted of considering it as zero?

Answer (score 3):

I would put a definition query on your layer that is something like:

```
VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

Or something like that. That way the tool will ignore them.